# How to display the length value from a length macro made by \pgfmathsetlengthmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf

I make a length macro by `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` from `tikz` to draw a rule like this:

```
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\bvar}{\textwidth - 5cm} 
\rule{\bvar}{5mm}
```

It works fine as expected.

Then I want to show the length value by `\the\bvar` but fail.

Why does \the\bvar not work since \bvar is a length macro? And how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a clue in the name of the command. Here's the definition of `\pgfsetlengthmacro` from `pgfmathcalc.code.tex`:

```
\def\pgfmathsetlengthmacro#1#2{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfmath@x{#2}% ❶
    \edef#1{\the\pgfmath@x}% ❷
    \pgfmath@smuggleone{#1}% ❸
  \endgroup%
}
```

What's happening here is that first ❶ we set a `\dimen` with the calculated value. Then ❷ the value is stored in a macro by using `\edef` and `\the\pgfmath@x`. So if the value of `\pgfmath@x` was, say, `47pt`, the macro will expand to `47pt`. Finally ❸ through some trickery that I won't get into here, the value that was defined is allowed to exist outside the group. Note that by putting all the code inside a group, the code avoids overwriting the internally used `\dimen` which might be used for other calculations elsewhere (although this is the only use of that `\dimen` in `pgfmathcalc.code.tex`).

Now as for **why** this is happening, there are two things worth being aware of. One is that there aren't really `\dimen` macros. There are, in fact, just 255 `\dimen` *registers* available to TeX/LaTeX¹. Because of this, we can't just treat `\dimen`s like variables since they're very much a finite resource. In fact, without loading any packages at all, the LaTeX kernel will have grabbed 138 of them already. By storing a value in a macro instead of a `\dimen` register, you avoid using up this resource unnecessarily.

As you've noted, the resulting macro seems to act identically to a `\dimen` although there are some key differences, most notably that you can write, e.g., `0.5\somedimen` and get a result of half the value in `\somedimen`. Doing this with a macro will instead expand to, say. 0.547.0pt which will give an error.

Since it's a macro, you can just type `\bvar` where you want to get the value, whether it's typeset in the text or output to the console with `\typeout`.

---

1. LaTeX renames `\dimen`s to `lengths` but they're the same thing. `\newlength{\foo}` and `\newdimen\foo` ultimately each have the same effect although the LaTeX version of the command includes guards to make sure that you don't inadvertently overwrite an existing command.

Comment: So, `\newlength{\aaa}`, `\setlength{]aaa}{5pt}`, the length value of \aaa is store in a register?

Comment: Yes. That’s what’s happening under the hood.

Comment: For calculation, is there difference  between values store in register and in macro?

Comment: With etex there are more dimen available than 256.

Comment: Thank you all  so much for these detail useful knowledge!